# How do I make a client socket receive data from another socket in a non-blocking manner?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tkinter

I am trying to make my client socket non-blocking. But unsuccessful. I'm not sure how to fix it.
I am trying to build a simple chat box and I am using tkinter for the GUI.

**The main part that is to note is the *while loop* that I have segmented within the code**

My client code is:

```
    .
    .
    .
    class GroupFrame(Frame):
        def __init__(self, master):
            super().__init__(master)
            global memList
            global rootHome
            self.master.geometry("400x500")
            self.master.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
            self.master.title("PowerPuff Chat Girls")

            #TextArea
            self.ChatLog = Text(self, bd=0, bg="light grey", height="13", width="55", font="Arial")
            self.ChatLog.insert(END, 'Welcome to the PowerPuff Chat, ' + username + '\n', 'INIT')
            self.ChatLog.config(state=DISABLED)
            self.ChatLog.tag_config('INIT', foreground='red', justify=CENTER)
            self.ChatLog.tag_config('BLUE', foreground='blue', justify=LEFT)
            self.ChatLog.tag_config('BLK', foreground='black', justify=RIGHT)

            #ScrollBar
            self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self, command = self.ChatLog.yview, cursor="heart")
            self.ChatLog['yscrollcommand'] = self.scrollbar.set

            #EntryBox
            self.EntryBox = Text(self, bg="white", width="29", height="5", font="Arial")
            self.EntryBox.bind("<KeyRelease-Return>", lambda event: sendData(self.EntryBox.get(1.0, END)))

            #SendButton
            self.SendButton = Button(self, font=30, text="Send", width="11", height=1,
                            bg="white", fg='navy blue', activebackground="#FACC2E",  command=lambda: sendData(self.EntryBox.get(1.0, END)))

            #Place them on Screen
            self.scrollbar.place(x=380, y=6, height=386)
            self.ChatLog.place(x=8, y=6, height=405, width=370)
            self.EntryBox.place(x=128, y=425, height=60, width=248)
            self.SendButton.place(x=6, y=425, height=60)

            def sendData(param):
                if param == '\n\n':
                    self.EntryBox.delete(1.0, END)
                    return
                if len(param) > 1:
                    if '\n\n' in param:
                        # strip both the carriage return and appened with only one.
                        param = param.rstrip('\n')
                        param = param + '\n'
                    self.EntryBox.delete(1.0, END)
                    insertText(1, '>>' + param)
                    s.sendall(str.encode(param))
                    # data = s.recv(4500)

            def inspectData(data):
                if 'joined the chat **\n' in data.decode('utf-8'):
                    insertText(3, data.decode('utf-8'))
                else:
                    insertText(2, '>>' + data.decode('utf-8'))
                self.ChatLog.see(END)  # this shows the END of the chatlog; auto scroll down

            def insertText(num, param):
                self.ChatLog.config(state=NORMAL)
                if num == 1:
                    self.ChatLog.insert(END, param, 'BLK')
                if num ==2 :
                    self.ChatLog.insert(END, param, 'BLUE')
                if num ==3:
                    self.ChatLog.insert(END, param, 'INIT')
                self.ChatLog.config(state=DISABLED)

  *******************************************************
             while True:
                try:
                    data = s.recv(4096)
                    if(data):
                         inspectData(data)
                except:
                    break
 *******************************************************

page = Tk()
page.geometry("400x500")
page.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
pf = HomeFrame(page)
page.mainloop()
```

With my current code, when I run it the client just freezes when it is currently in the *GroupFrame* Frame.
I am not sure why this happens. And If i haven't made my question clear please let me know so I can provide some images and parts of code that will help.

Comment: Your indentation seems to be off. Please fix that, to make it possible to understand your code.

Comment: @JohanL : fixed the indentation. The last 5  lines of the code must be outside the class indent because it runs throughout the program.

Comment: It still looks the same to me. I agree with the sentiment that the `while` loop must be outside, but I am not seeing it.

Comment: @JohanL : The while loop is inside the class indent. The last file lines of the code which is creating a window and frame(tkinter) is outside. I don't see anything wrong with the indentation, sorry. please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: `def __init__` is on the same indentation level as `class GroupFrame` then all the other methods are indented one more level. Are they functions local to `__init__`? Because with the current indentation, that is what they become.

Comment: @JohnanL.      Sorry my bad. Error in indentation while copy pasting into the text box in here. changed now

Comment: OK, that makes the `while` loop part of the `GroupFrame`s init method, meaning it will never return. However, I never see any `GroupFrame` object ever instantiated, unless `HomeFrame`and `GroupFrame`are supposed to be the same?

Comment: `HomeFrame` is instantiated first and then it is destroyed to create `GroupFrame`. Sorry that I didn't post that part of the code here. It would have been too long and a slightly unnecessary I thought

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my issue. In case anyone else has a similar problem of polling for a data received from another socket within a Tkinter loop. This is how I fixed it:

Create a function that polls through the socket within your Frame and make a separate thread within that Frame that runs it.

*Code:*

```
def polling():
    while True:
        try:
            polledData = s.recv(4096)
            print(polledData.decode('utf-8'))
        except:
            pass #or you can print out the exception if you need to.

threading.Thread(target = polling, args=[]).start()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different problems with the code as presented. The main issue is the `while` loop in the `__init__` function. This will make `__init__` run forever (assuming the socket is blocking). This, in turn, will block the main loop of Tk, and therefore the whole program.

When working with Tk, one must realize that Tk owns the main loop. This means that one must always allow Tk to run, to dequeue events posted to its internal event queue. If your program needs to do something else, like, for example, listen to a socket, this has to be done, either in a separate thread or to be incorporated in the Tk loop.

Unfortunately there is no general way to make the socket input part of the Tk loop. However, what we can do, is to post a certain event using `after` that will ensure the main loop will call a predefined function after a certain time. This can be used in order to create a solution, where it is possible to poll the socket at certain times, and check if there are new data to process.

Another way is to run the socket in a separate thread, that posts messages (through a synchronized `Queue`) to the Tk thread. That might by a more general solution, but it still requires the main loop to poll the queue instead of the socket.

All of this is quite a bit to digest. I suggest that you try to reduce your example further, and then ask questions on smaller examples if there are parts that are still hard to grasp.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try working out your first suggestion